# Auth problems with OAuth (Facebook App), session is not available?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I want to read all birthdays of the friends from current user. I use the new Graph API of facebook. I request the authorization of the permissions (`read_friendslist` and `friends_birthday`) based on Facebooks [insights example](https://github.com/facebook/insights-api-sample) and [php-sdk example](https://github.com/facebook/php-sdk/tree/master/examples). For reading the friendslist and the user details I used the Graph API with Facebook PHP SDK.

The upcoming code snippets are a short self contained correct example of my approach. If I try to use my app it requests login, then asks for permissions and then fails in printing all my friends due to the fact that no session is available. What's wrong here?

First is the `birthday.php` which is used by the following `index.php`, I removed some boilerplate code or code I think it's not causing this problem (identified by [...]). You can find the complete code on the end of this question.

```
<?php
function get_birthday_of_friends() {

    $fbconfig['appid' ]  = "MY_APP_ID";
    $fbconfig['secret']  = "MY_APP_SECRET";

    try{
            include_once "facebook/src/facebook.php";
    }
    catch(Exception $o){
             // [...] log error
    }
    // Create our Application instance.
    $facebook = new Facebook(array(
      'appId'  => $fbconfig['appid'],
      'secret' => $fbconfig['secret'],
      'cookie' => true,
    ));

    $session = $facebook->getSession();

    $fbme = null;
    // Session based graph API call.
    if ($session) {
               // [...] return birthdays
    } else {
        echo "No session found";
    }
}
?>
```

The required `lib.php` is identically with the *insights example*.

```
<?php

    // [...] Include and define app-id etc.

function get_access_token($base_url) {
  if (isset($_REQUEST['access_token'])) {
    return $_REQUEST['access_token'];
  }
  $params = array();
  $params['client_id'] = APP_ID;
  $params['redirect_uri'] = $base_url;
  if (!isset($_REQUEST['code'])) {
    $params['scope'] = 'read_friendlists, friends_birthday';
    $url = FacebookMethods::getGraphApiUrl('oauth/authorize', $params);
    throw new RedirectionException($url);
  } else {
    $params['client_secret'] = APP_SECRET;
    $params['code'] = $_REQUEST['code'];
    $url = FacebookMethods::getGraphApiUrl('oauth/access_token');
    $response = FacebookMethods::fetchUrl($url, $params);
    $response = strstr($response, 'access_token=');
    $result = substr($response, 13);
    $pos = strpos($result, '&');
    if ($pos !== false) {
      $result = substr($result, 0, $pos);
    }
    return $result;
    }
}

    // [...] Call get_access_token() and get_birthday_of_friends()!
?>
```

Can you help me with that? I added the whole source code on pastebin.com if this helps you to identify my problem. Source code on pastebin.com for "[index.php](http://pastebin.com/MTjNFExQ)" and "[birthday.php](http://pastebin.com/GNWue1Qi)".

Thank you in advance!

Comment: did you really post the real secret key for your app? Edit your post and remove it, it's not relevant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If no session is available, I had to redirect to the login page and require the extended permissions with the parameters. This did the trick to me, thanks to manuelpedrera for helping me out.

```
$facebook->getLoginUrl(array('req_perms' => 'read_friendlists, [...]'));
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if the method that you are using is deprecated or not, but I know it's the old way and you should try with the new one in order to get the auth token.

Take a look at this link:
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/signed_request/

In a glance, you have to:

- Get the `signed_request` parameter from $_REQUEST.
- Use the sample function provided in
  the link to decode it Once you decode
  it, you will have an array in which
  there is a parameter called
  `oauth_token`.
- With this parameter,    you can start
  making calls to the    Graph by
  appending it to the URL e.g.
  *https://graph.facebook.com/PROFILE_ID/pictures/?access_token=OAUTH_TOKEN*

Make sure that you have `Oauth 2.0 for Canvas` enabled into the Configuration settings of your app (Advanced tab).

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I found a solution for this, but you helped me to point out that I use a deprecated API.

Answer (score 0):

I think in some browsers there's a prblem with third party cookies. Are you testing in Safari? And also, try to add permissions to the loginUrl - it's a bit more simple than adding and requesting the permissions with oauth.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, what do you mean with "add permissions to the login-url"? Can you explain that a little bit or provide a small example? I'm testing with Crome/Firefox.